# Using Angular for upvote => swipe functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to incorporate a swiping feature into my app via angular.

Idea is as follows

1. User rates item in Angular model. Based on input. Controller queues up the next item for view
2. After rating, item "swipes" out of view and angular introduces the new item.

Any ideas on how to approach this functionality? I'm new to angular but I'm having trouble figuring out which part of Angular I need to explore:

I think ng-repeat will be necessary, but they're all occupying the same space on the DOM

ideas?

Comment: If you're showing one item at a time, you shouldn't need ngRepeat. You may want to look into ngAnimate, if simple CSS transitions are not enough to achieve the sliding effect you want. (Also, considering using the word "slide" to refer to animation; "swipe" implies user interaction on a touch screen device.)

Comment: ng-Animate seems promising. I'm having a good time reading up on it. Is there anyway to have a "queue" of items waiting to "slide in" after the user has provided a rating?

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably use a rest api to fetch n items in an array, then make http requests every so often to get the next n items and add them to the end of the array. Drop old items off the beginning of the array if there's no need to go backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has [$swipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/service/$swipe) service attached as a part of the [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) module.
You may use swipe events to fetch views simply by binding actions inside your controller.

Here is a simple [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbw4nr7g/4/).

Here is a little more complicated **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbw4nr7g/5/)** revealing items rendered by `ng-repeat`.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngTouch']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.index = 0;

  // Increment action on swipe right event
  $scope.next = function($event) {
    $scope.index++;
  };
  // Decrement action on swipe left event
  $scope.prev = function($event) {
    $scope.index--;
  };
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for to get me started thank you

Comment: Cheers mate. You should check out the second demo provided as well .